# Rails ignoring default scope's order and limit condition on includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I am facing a wierd issue with respect to Default Scoping and Eager Loading.

Consider the following structure

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  default_scope -> {order(:foo_column1).limit(1)}
end
```

Given this simple association and assuming every Foo has 20 bars, I am doing the following queries.

When I directly refer the `bars` association, the default scope is getting applied happily and I am getting only 1 bar in the result as I've limited/ordered under default scope.

```
A.first.bars.size
=> 1
```

However when I eager load and try to get the bars object, it is bringing all the bars. This is not applying the `order` and `limit` condition in the `default` scope. (however if it had a `where` condition, it applies it)

```
A.includes(:bar).references(:bar).first.bars.size
=> 20

OR

A.eager_load(:bar).first.bars.size
=> 20
```

How to avoid this scenario. Note: I know I can use joins and avoid this perhaps using a sub query, but I pretty much want to do this by eager loading with minimal queries and able to access via AR Objects.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an explicit scope rather than the default scope.

```
scope :one_bar, -> { bars.order(:foo_column1).limit(1) }
```

Then try

```
Foo.eager_load(:bars).first.one_bar
```

Alteratively, you might even try:

```
scope :first_bar, -> { bars.order(:foo_column1).first }
```

Then this won't be a relation, but rather the desired `Bar` object:

```
Foo.eager_load(:bars).first.first_bar
```